# Have a more aggressive filter for duplicate questions by the same user (i.e. uppercase/lowercase)

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

<sup>Note: this is not the same as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127269/180276); that one's about duplicates in general. I'm talking about the automatic filter that disallows duplicate posts by the same user.</sup>

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18658/3808) was recently posted on Code Golf.SE. Here's an image for <2kers there:

[image: screenshot]

Then, [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18664/3808) was posted a few minutes after:

[image: screenshot]

Now, there's supposed to be a filter that blocks questions with the same title that are posted in a short span of time.

That didn't seem to work here.

Spot the difference? Turns out that in the new one, the word "flag" is lowercase.

Is that **really** enough for it to be considered an entirely different question?

So, my request is for the filter to be a *bit* more aggressive. Some ways it could do this:

- Ignore case (**especially** this; I don't know why it doesn't do this already anyway)
- Ignore punctuation and whitespace
- Consider it a duplicate if there is only an `n`-character change, where `n` could be something like 5 (i.e. `Lets draw Flag of Nepal` == `Let's draw the flag of Nepal!`)

Comment: I can agree to have just a bit more aggressive filter, but not too much. Just keep the middle of the street. Let's also consider the PRO of similar question. One pro of letting users open similar question is for Search Engine Optimization. Another is to allow more people to answer similar question.. Obviously similar doesn't mean equal.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any links on the matter, but I'm under the impression that the filter compares the entirety of the questions, not just the title. Note the addition of "But there is only one requirement, you are not allowed to use web resources." in the body of the second.